# I move a folder in Android root directory to SDcard directory in internal phone memory. Is there a way to restore it back?

Tags: adb, 4.1-jelly-bean, file-system

I move a folder in the Android root directory to SDcard directory in the internal phone memory. The folder was `custpack` in the root directory and the phone will not boot now.

I can still access a recovery mode, but it only has a stock recovery from the manufacturer. No custom recovery available for my phone.

- Is there any way I can grab contents of the SDcard directory using developers tools?

One of the menus in the stock recovery is to ADB side load file name.

- Is there any hope I can access the phone memory using a PC somehow and restore the folder?

In the Android stock recovery menu, I have the option to install package from an SD card. The phone does have an SD card slot.

- Is it possible to create a zip file that will some how restore the `custpack` folder back to root directory? I do have the deleted folder in my PC.

Answer (score 0):

One method you can try is download and use [Aroma File Manager](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1646108). 
It's a recovery based file manager. Means you can access all files and do all file operations like cut, move etc.

But not sure if it will work on un rooted device. 
But you can try.

Comment: thanks. I will try Aroma. But looks like I have to push the aroma file manager back to the phone? I tried to push files in stock recovery it keeps giving me a message "error: closed" . I did root the phone using VROOT before I delete the custpack folder.

Comment: First copy aroma to your SD card from computer. Then use it in your phone. Then you can move the specified folder to your root folder whichever.

Comment: Got it.. let me try aroma file manager.. I hope I can run it .